# Dynamics 365 - enable a custom entity to appear in the regarding lookup

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

When I create a task, I'd like to set a record of a custom entity as "Regarding". The solution explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-app/enable-a-custom-entity-to-appear-in-the-regarding-lookup) does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to complete all these steps:

1. An entity must be **Activities** enabled for it to appear in the **Regarding** lookup. [Enable a custom entity to appear in the Regarding lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-app/enable-a-custom-entity-to-appear-in-the-regarding-lookup).
2. An entity must also be enabled for Unified Interface for it to appear in the Regarding lookup. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/mobile-app/set-up-dynamics-365-for-phones-and-dynamics-365-for-tablets#enable-entities-for-the-mobile-app).
3. Open the App designer, Add > Entities and then select the entity you want to add and complete the addition by including all assets. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-app/filter-entities-and-views)

[image]

[image]

[image]